# Angularfire2: Proper approach to check if user is logged in?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I wan't to allow only logged in users to access a certain site.
What's the proper way of checking if a user is logged in on load?

The code below is my first try, don't really know if it works though.
Of course I already wrote db rules, now I want to complete the behavior visually for the user.

```ts
this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
   if (auth) {
      //route to other view
   } else {
      //do whatever
   }
});
```

Comment: You should use angular 2 routing guards. On top of that, keep a lookout for this https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/343

Answer (score 3):

You should consider use angular 2 guards, like [canActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html). They can help you to do validation before the routing happens. This way you can prevent the navigation of unauthorized users.

As say early, this approach works. If you want do transformation over the auth information. Probably, you should use observables methods like map, flatmap, concatMap.