# Angular + Firebase auth: how to access the user information from any component

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, state-management

I have a component (actually, the app component) that calls a firebase anonymous sign in function on `ngAfterContentInit`:

```js
  ngAfterContentInit(){
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
  .then(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('the uid of the anonymous user is '+ user.uid);
        // User is signed in
      } else {
        // User is signed out
      }
    });
    // Signed in..
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
  }
```

It is working, and the `uid` of the anonymous user is getting printed.

However, now I need to access this `uid` from another component. I haven't set up an auth.service.ts file or anything, just using the above function.

How would I go about this? I am new to Angular (coming from ReactJS), and in ReactJS I would have put the user information inside the Redux State. Is there something similar in Angular? [I am already using the required modules to connect Angular to Firebase Auth].

Alternatively, is there an easy way to access the signed-in user information without having to deal with state management in the first place?

Many thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is when you use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener to route your users to pages they only can see as authenticated users. In that case you can get the current user with the `currentUser` form firebase auth like this:

```js
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
  // ...
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

Make sure that you are on a page that is only visible when authenticated and check for `null` valuein user.

Comment: I ended up doing something related. Followed this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717408/how-to-get-currently-logged-in-auth-state-user-from-angularfire2
One of the answers was exactly what I needed (the one that starts with `this.afAuth.authState.subscribe...`. Thank you anyway